# Data Caching in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am a learner.I am learning Caching in ASP.NET.There are three types of caching in ASP.NET.

1.Page output caching.

2.Partial Output caching.

3.Data Caching.

In Page output caching, all the rendered content of the page saved in Cache and page every time re-execute.

In Partial Output caching, we can apply caching rules on different parts of pages.

**But Data Caching, I didn't understand.**

Could anyone please explain me Data Caching?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms data caching is storing data in memory for quick access. Typically information that is costly to obtain (in terms of performance) is stored in the cache. One of the more common items stored in a cache in a Web application environment is commonly displayed database values; by caching such information, rather than relying on repeated database calls, the demand on the Web server and database server's system resources are decreased and the Web application's scalability increased. As Microsoft eloquently puts it, "Caching is a technique widely used in computing to increase performance by keeping frequently accessed or expensive data in memory. In the context of a Web application, caching is used to retain pages or data across HTTP requests and reuse them without the expense of recreating them."

Read more : [.NET Data Caching](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111559/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100902-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is about caching application data (using the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class) - persistence of some objects (values).